# Do independent random variables implies conditionally independence too?

Tags: probability-theory, soft-question

Let $X$ and $Y$ be mutually independent random variables i-e $$P(X,Y)=P(X) \cdot P(Y)$$ where $P(X)$ is the probability mass function of $X$. Is it possible that some condition (if exists) will make them conditionally dependent? i-e $$P(X,Y|Z)\neq P(X|Z) \cdot P(Y|Z)$$ Or ***unconditionally independent* RVs will always remain *conditionally independent* too**?

Comment: Say you are tossing a penny ($X$) and a dime ($Y$) and let $Z$ be the event "the coins match".

Comment: The expression $\mathbb P(X)$ does not make sense. $X$ is a measurable function defined on a probability space, and $\mathbb P$ is a probability measure defined on some $\sigma$-algebra on that space.

Comment: @Math1000 Since this question apparently was not edited, I wonder where this expression appeared ?

Comment: Presumably $P(X)$ is being used to refer to the distribution function of $X$. But this is certainly not standard notation.

Comment: @lulu  I'm interested in when $X$ and $Y$ are not disjoint events.

Comment: @kaka what do you mean by disjoint?

Comment: I don't know what "disjoint" means in this context.   If you have additional assumptions on $X,Y$, add them to your post.

Comment: From disjoint I mean: random variables whose pmf is defined on the same set and not two disjoint sets, like the case of penny and dime which are two random variables defined on disjoint sets.